# How to implement remote blob storage in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document, rbs

How to implement remote blob storage in SharePoint 2013.Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Before you begin this operation, review the following information about prerequisites:

- The user account used to perform the steps in the Provision a BLOB
  store for each content database section must be a member of the
  db_owner fixed database role on each database that you are
  configuring RBS for.
- The user account installing the client library in the steps in the
  Install the RBS client library on each web server section must be a
  member of the Administrators group on all of the computers where you
  are installing the library.
- The user account enabling RBS in the Enable RBS for each content
  database section must have sufficient permissions to run Windows
  PowerShell.

**Now follow the steps below:**

- [Enable FILESTREAM on the database server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631%28v=office.15%29.aspx#enable)
- [Provision a BLOB store for each content database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631%28v=office.15%29.aspx#provision)
- [Install the RBS client library on each web server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631%28v=office.15%29.aspx#library)
- [Enable RBS for each content database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631%28v=office.15%29.aspx#enableRBS)
- [Assign db_owner permissions to the web application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631%28v=office.15%29.aspx#dbOwnPerm)
- [Test the RBS installation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631%28v=office.15%29.aspx#testRBS)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631(v=office.15).aspx